# MMS Cannot connect to local machine for backup purposes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-mms

I am trying to use mongoDB MMS backup functionality.  I am getting the following error when trying to connect in the "Add Host" part of the wizard.

**Unable to detect host within check interval.**

I have MongoDB 2.6.4 on a my Windows 7 laptop. I've created an admin user with the following privileges:

```
> db.createUser(
... {
... user: "admin",
... pwd: "xxx"
... roles: [
... "clusterAdmin",
... "readAnyDatabase",
... "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
... "userAdminAnyDatabase"
... ]
... }
... );
```

I run `mongod --auth`.

Now I try to connect via MMS using MONGODB-CR Auth mechanism and get the error I described above.

In the log I get many errors like the following:

```
[2014/10/21 09:13:59] [monitoring.info] [monitoring-agent/components/agent.go:551] 
Starting 2 marshal handlers
[2014/10/21 09:14:21] [monitoring.error] [monitoring-agent/components/agent.go:314] 
Failed to fetch Conf
Failure getting conf. Op: Get Err: dial tcp [I've hide the IP]:443: ConnectEx tcp:
 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after
 a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed 
 to respond.
at monitoring-agent/components/conf.go:249
at monitoring-agent/components/agent.go:312
at mongodb.com/monitoring-agent/monitoring-agent-service.go:129
at winsvc/svc/service.go:200
at pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445
```

Using Robomongo 0.8.4 client I was able to log-in using the user and pass.

I want to be able for MMS to connect to my local machine and initialize a backup of the databases on my machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check if the agent if running properly on your local machine?

Comment: Based on the error `Failed to fetch Conf` it seems like the MMS Backup agent isn't able to connect to mms.mongodb.com to get its configuration. I would check that you have entered the correct `mmsApiKey` in your agent config. If you can comment with a link to your MMS group, one of the MongoDB support team members can also have a look at your group.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error while configuring my mongodb-mms. On my Ops Manager server I had configured my TLS connections correctly, but on the mongo server being monitored I had the incorrect TLS certificate. The log `/var/log/mongodb-mms-automation/monitoring-agent.log` on the agent I was trying to monitor helped me out:

```
[2020/04/26 02:05:47.363] [discovery.collector-mongo2:27017.error] [components/discovery.go:contexts:580] Discovery commands requiring authentication will be skipped.
Failed to get connectionStatus. Err: `auth error: round trip error: (UserNotFound) Could not find user "CN=mms,OU=TestClientCertificateOrgUnit,O=TestClientCertificateOrg,L=TestClientCertificateLocality,ST=TestClientCertificateState,C=US" for db "$external"`
        at monitoring-agent/components/dialing.go:442
        at monitoring-agent/components/dialing.go:200
        at monitoring-agent/components/dialing.go:306
        at monitoring-agent/components/dialing.go:323
        at louisaberger/procexec/concurrency.go:45
        at src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357
```

See [this page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/) to add in your `mms` user so that the user can authenticate correctly (or fix your certs if it's just a mixup).